# Traffic light control by one switch instead of $n$

Tags: combinatorics

There are $n$ three-position switches that control the red/yellow/green position of a single traffic light. Whenever the positions of $\textbf{all}$ switches are changed, the colour of the light changes. Prove that the colour of the light is actually controlled by only one switch.

The case $n=1$ is trivial and the case $n=2$ can be case-bashed in a lengthy way (if I have not missed some cases). But I do not have any general strategy and cannot even reformulate the problem in a sensible mathematical rigorous way.

I was also thinking that this 'three-position' might be attacked with $\mathbb{F}_3$? Or perhaps the $3$ does not really matter (this makes more sense but who knows).

Any help appreciated!

---

Another way to rephrase. You are given an a function $f:(\mathbb F_3)^n\to \mathbb F_3$, which has the property that for all $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n, y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n\in \mathbb F_3$ such that $x_1\neq y_1,x_2\neq y_2,\dots,x_n\neq y_n$, it holds that
$$
f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\neq f(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)
$$
The interpretation is that each $x_i$ represents the position of one of the switches, and the output of $f$ is the color of the traffic light. The above conditions means that changing all switches should change the color of the light.

The goal is to prove that $f$ is actually only determined by one argument. In other words, there exists a function $g:\mathbb F_3\to \mathbb F_3$, and an index $i\in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$, such that
$$
f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=g(x_i)
$$
for all inputs $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$.

Comment: This is very unclear. What exactly do we know about these switches?

Comment: I think it's a famous problem about vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}_3$, which I don't remember exactly.

Comment: @FranklinPezzutiDyer So let's say WLOG that the light initially shows 'red' and that the switches, having states 1,2,3 each, are all at state 1. Then only when we change each '1' to 2 or 3 the 'red' will change to 'yellow' or 'green' although we do not know in what way.

Comment: I found the puzzle. See here https://www.cs.cmu.edu/puzzle/solution13.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Induction on $n$. The result is trivial for $n=1$. Assume it is true for $n-1$.

*Case 1*. For some *particular* setting of the first $n-1$ switches, the output is determined by the setting of switch $n$. Suppose the setting of the first $n-1$ switches is $(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})$. So wlog the assumption is that $f(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1},i)=i$ (for $i=1,2,3$). [If the outputs for these three settings occur in a different order, we can just relabel the positions of switch $n$]. Let $(b_1,\dots,b_{n-1})$ be a **disjoint** setting of the first $n-1$ switches, ie $a_j\ne b_j$ for $j=1,2,\dots,n-1$. Then $(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1},2)$ and $(b_1,\dots,b_{n-1},1)$ are disjoint, so $f(b_1,\dots,b_{n-1},1)\ne2=f(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1},2)$. Similarly $f(b_1,\dots,b_{n-1},1)\ne3=f(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1},3)$. Hence $f(b_1,\dots,b_{n-1},1)=1$. Similarly, $f(b_1,\dots,b_{n-1},2)=2$ and $f(b_1,\dots,b_{n-1},3)=3$.

Now we claim that *any* setting of the first $n-1$ switches can be reached by two such steps. To get from $(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})$ to $(c_1,\dots,c_{n-1})$, we pick any $b_i$ different from both $a_i$ and $c_i$ (where for some $i$ we may have $a_i=c_i$). Then the first move is from $(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})$ to $(b_1,\dots,b_{n-1})$, and the second move is from $(b_1,\dots,b_{n-1})$ to $(c_1,\dots,c_{n-1})$. We thus end up with the output being solely determined by the last switch.

*Case 2*. For any setting $(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})$ of the first $n-1$ switches we can find two settings of the last switch which give the same output. We define this to be the output $g(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})$ for the first $n-1$ switches.

Suppose $(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})$ and $(b_1,\dots,b_{n-1})$ are disjoint. Then we can find $h\ne k\in\{1,2,3\}$ st $g(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})=f(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1},h)\ne f(b_1,\dots,b_{n-1},k)=g(b_1,\dots,b_{n-1})$. So by induction $g$ is determined by one of the first $n-1$ switches. So wlog we have $g(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})=a_1$. Hence for any $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$ we have $f(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1},i)=a_1$ for two values of $i\in\{1,2,3\}$.

Now pick $b_i,c_i\in\{1,2,3\}$ st $b_i=a_i+1,c_i=a_i+2\bmod 3$ for each $i$. Then for two values of $i$ in $\{1,2,3\}$ we have $f(b_1,\dots,b_{n-1},i)=g(b_1,\dots,b_{n-1})=b_1$. So given any $j\in\{1,2,3\}$ we can find $k\ne j$ with $f(b_1,\dots,b_{n-1},k)=b_1$. But $(a_1,\dots,a_{n01},j)$ and $(b_1,\dots,b_{n-1},k)$ are disjoint, so $f(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1},j)\ne b_1$. Similarly, $f(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1},j)\ne c_1$. So we must have $f(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1},j)=a_1$. That completes the induction. $\Box$